# Some characters replaced with question mark symbols

Tags: c#

I am trying to read from a file line-by-line and write to another file. However, after writing the file some characters (for example quotation `"` and apostrophe `'` signs) have been replaced with question marks (؟). How can I fix this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  int counter = 0;
  string line;

  // Read the file and display it line by line.
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\test.txt");
  System.IO.StreamWriter OutPutFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\out.txt");
  System.IO.StreamWriter lineOutPutFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\lineoutput.txt");

  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    OutPutFile.Write(line);
    OutPutFile.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(line);
    Console.Write(" ");
    // Call your function here
    counter++;
  }

  file.Close();
  OutPutFile.Close();
  lineOutPutFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: `new System.IO.StreamReader` with no encoding uses UTF-8. I bet your test.txt file is not UTF-8. Are you sure your file actually contains quotation marks (") and commas (,) and not double-quotes (“) and single-quotes (’)?

Comment: Your encoding of the output should match encoding of the input

Comment: Try adding the second parameter `System.Text.Encoding.Default` when you create the StreamReader.

Comment: hi Mostafa, can you please confirm if the below answer helped solve your problem, if yes please consider clicking on the green tickbox to accept it, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

StreamReader is designed for character input in a particular encoding, therefore you can specify the encoding like below

```
new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); // UTF-8 that is the most common form of unicode encoding
```

You may also try the Default encoding, which uses the current system's ANSI codepage.

```
new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

> **From MSDN**:
>
> **Encoding is the process of transforming a set of Unicode characters
>   into a sequence of bytes**
>
> **Encoding Classes allows error to change to '?' character, the reason why use see ? in your output**

---

**P.S:** *You can open your Notepad and determine which encoding it has used for the file*

**NOTE:** *Remember to Dispose the StreamReader and StreamWriter objects after its use to release all the resources used by it*

**References:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8